# Rails - Querying a JSON Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ahoy

In my Rails 5 app, I'm using the [Ahoy gem](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy) which uses a jsonb field (called `properties`) that I don't know how to query.

A sample of the data in the `properties` field:

```
"{\"id\":\"11\"}"
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Find the records created in the last seven days (using the `time` field)
2. Group the records by the `id` in the `properties` field
3. Order the records based on which `id` had the most records

I tried this:

```
@foo = Ahoy::Event.where(name: "Viewed Product").where(time: 7.days.ago..Time.now).group("properties(id)").order('COUNT("properties(id)") DESC')
```

but I received the error, `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "properties(id)" doe not exist`

I found this [somewhat similar question](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/issues/198) in the issues for the gem, so I tried breaking the query into parts:

```
@foo = Ahoy::Event.where(name: "Viewed Product").where(time: 7.days.ago..Time.now)
@foo.group("properties REGEXP '[{,]\"id\"...).count
```

but then my IDE gives the error `unterminated string meets the end of file`.

Can someone please help me determine what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL, I believe that you would have to refer to json columns like this:
`.group("properties ->> 'id'")`

Comment: Yes, I saw a post mentioning that.  When I tried that I received `PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "ahoy_events.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: That is understandable. Check this link ( http://bernardoamc.github.io/sql/2015/05/04/group-by-non-aggregate-columns/ ) for details. You may want to modify your query as per your use case. However, in any case you will have to use ```properties ->> 'id'``` if you plan to query on the jsonb column.